# binance on site data and api data doesnt match

Tags: binance

When I collect say 1 minute historical kline data through the API, I see differente close times to what I see on the site checking the same time's candle. (I am matching data to UTC time that is not a factor here.)
Do you have any tips what might be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

I have realised that the site doesn't refresh correctly, and I only needed to reload the site to match the one that gets returned through the api

Comment: Yeah, the JSON API used by the web interface seems to just fall asleep after a few hours, and stop refreshing.